# Page not found suggestions should include linked questions

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, linked-questions

The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20839622/notifications-for-new-github-project-releases is deleted, and for low rep users it gives a list of "similar questions". However, that list doesn't include the linked question [Watching new tags on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685796/watching-new-tags-on-github?noredirect=1&lq=1) .

Assuming that people are smarter than computers, and that we value the contributions of people, we should include linked questions that are suggested by people, not just what Stack Overflow's algorithm decides is similar.

Comment: *Problem "solved"* ....